# What is "Apply security filter in both directions" (normal vs security filter)?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have users dim table with userid, username, useremail

RLS is applied on this table using the username() filter

User dim table connects to sales fact table on userid, so a user can see only his sales.

There is relationship from sales fact table to company dim table on company_id (1 company has many sales, 1:M). On this relationship, I have set cross filter direction to `Both`, so selecting few sale fact records shows (filters) corresponding company names.

When I made the bidirectional relationship, there is an option called "Apply security filter in both directions". Whether this is checkmarked or not, either ways the filter of selected sale is passed as an filter into the company dim table.

So what is the use of ticking this feature? What is difference between normal filter and security filter?

Comment: Hey @variable,
Did it answer your query ?

Comment: Hi Nandan, your example is explaining the use case of `Apply security filter in both directions` between dimension tables. Where as my question is asking what is the purpose of this setting on the relationship between fact and dimension.

Answer (score 3):

For a RLS to be effective across multiple instances of Dim table and not explicitly on the one which we created ,we have to explicitly Apply security filter in both directions.

For Eg:
Consider I have 2 DIM tables :
a) Employee
b) Company

And 2 fact tables :
a) Employee Salary
b) sales

There is 1:m relation among Company and sales
and 1:1 relation among Employee and EmployeeSalary
and 1:m relation among Company and Employee

Assume the RLS is applied on Employee table based on login .

In case if the bidirection filter is not applied, in case of a slice by company for sales and Employee salary ; the result would be :

1. for salary , the employee would be able to just see his salary
2. whereas he would be able to see sales of all companies

In case if the bidirection filter would be present, then the user would be able to see just the sales of the companies he is tagged to.

Hope this clarifies the need of bidirection filter.

The below link would provide detailed explanation :

https://asankap.wordpress.com/2018/05/28/how-does-row-level-security-works-when-there-is-a-bi-directional-filter-in-power-bi-tabular-model/

Comment: You have answered about the use of bidirectional filter. But you have not answered about "Apply security filter in both directions". Assuming bidirectional is set in your example, then loggedin employee will see only his company and sales for his company. So what is the impact of setting or not setting "Apply security filter in both directions"?

Comment: Hey @variable,
The Apply Security filter in both direction means the RLS would be applied to all data directly or indirectly related to the value on which RKS is set up.
Since in this case the RLS is on user , all values directly or indirectly related to user would get filtered out.
Like Employee and Employee salary is directly related : so irrespective of the bidirection filter, the data would have been filtered.

Comment: But employee and sales are related via company.
So in case if the bidirectional filter is not enabled ; the user would be able to see all sales data but enabling bidirectional security filter would ensure that RLS is applied to all relations thereby allowing the user to see sales of his own company.

Hope this clarifies.

https://asankap.wordpress.com/2018/05/28/how-does-row-level-security-works-when-there-is-a-bi-directional-filter-in-power-bi-tabular-model/

This link has detailed screenshots with proper examples for much more clear visualization of the property

Comment: I have read this link, and the example is very nice. I want to ask you - does `both directions` mean both sides of the bidirectional filter relationship. Or both sides of the dimension on which the RLS is applied?

Comment: Hi Nandan, your example is explaining the use case of `Apply security filter in both directions` between dimension tables. Where as my question is asking what is the purpose of this setting on the relationship between fact and dimension.